# Set range knob to min and max end

Tags: ionic2

i have a ion-range button I have set it to min and max value in dual knob but both the knob are located to the min value

```
   <ion-range dualKnobs="true"  [(ngModel)]="knobValues"  pin="true" min="50" max="250" color="dark" >
      <ion-label range-left > <b>50</b> </ion-label>
      <ion-label range-right > <b>250</b> </ion-label>
    </ion-range>
```

set this after my constructor(){}

```
 knobValues:{
  upper:100,
  lower:50
}
```

Currently i an getting like this

[image]

I need it to be like this on page load

[image]

Could someone help me

Comment: is it set _in_ the constructor or directly in the class?

Comment: ya inside class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In typescript, the way to set class variable is

```
 variable_name:type = value;
```

---

```
 knobValues:{
  upper:100,
  lower:50
}
```

Above you have set the type of `knobValues` and its content is undefined.

Set as

```
 knobValues:{ upper:number,lower:number}={
      upper:100,
      lower:50
    }
```